# How to achieve this effect for pictures in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, noise, research

I tried Torn edges, but my results are noticeably different from these pictures

[image: https://www.instagram.com/p/BoHdd2ijqNG/]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From original image - yeah, don't ask ;)

[image]

Add adjustment layer - Threshold

[image]

Flatten result.
Add layer mask [reveal all].
Select all, copy, alt/click mask, paste.
Invert. This should leave the black but make all the white transparent.

[image]

Add new layer, drop it behind.
Use paint bucket with flat purple.
Filter > Noise > Add Noise

result…

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My answer is similar to Tetsujin's method, but created non-destructively using a Threshold adjustment layer, grouped with the image layer, then the group set to "Multiply" mode.  A noise filter can then be applied to a purple background Smart Object.

For greater similarity to your examples, it's probably best to start off with a [photograph taken with low key lighting](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=low%20key%20portrait&qs=n&form=QBIR&sp=-1&pq=low%20key%20portrait&sc=8-16&sk=&cvid=EB8B46F6EE5F48818BF0EDF46A7DE76B) (i.e. dark background and strong highlights).

Example:

[image]

The benefit of doing this non-destructively is you can adjust the Threshold and Noise filters after applying them.